# .NET date formatting

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Consider:

```
Assert.Equal("11 Aug 2010", date.ToString(???);
```

Somehow `ToString("d MMM yyyy")` outputs "11 aug 2010". How can I make it to be `Aug` instead of `aug`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToString("d MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")`

works

Answer (score 0):

In that case how about using ToTitleCase():

ToTitleCase() method is hidden treasure of .Net Framework hosted by the System.Globalization.TextInfo namespace and can be used as shown below:

```
string sentence = "this is a title case EXAMPLE sentence";
string formattedSentence = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(sentence.ToLower());
```

Will result in "This Is A Title Case Example Sentence"

Comment: That `Assert` was just to show what i need. Funky style to format questions on stackoverflow. In application I'm developing - I'm just outputing it. Don't need to compare anything.

Comment: I have updated the code show ToTitleCase() method, in case you don't find anything suitable for your Date Formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I have this cheat sheet website that i have saved to my favourites

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm